# I am trying to access one of my plugins page but it is not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a login page that correctly authenticate users, the problem is that it does not find the next file to open it.

my files are as following

```
  **Plugin Root directory**
     |                  |
     myindex_2343.php   | 
                        **MyClasses directory**
                          |               |
                          Login_2343.php  Member_2343.php
```

Login_2343.php

```
<form name="mylogin" action="" method="post">
     .....
</form>
<?php
       if(isset($_POST['username']))
       {
            Authentication code goes here
            if(Authenticate)
            {
              echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="MyClasses 
              /Member_2343.php";</script>';
             }
        }
  ?>
```

The error message is as following:

```
   The requested URL /wordpress/wp-admin/MyClasses/Member_2343.php was not 
   found on this server.
```

Comment: what is the new url after redirect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your plugin root in window.location.href

```
<form name="mylogin" action="" method="post">
     .....
</form>
<?php
       if(isset($_POST['username']))
       {
            Authentication code goes here
            if(Authenticate)
            {
              echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/pluginroot/MyClasses 
              /Member_2343.php";</script>';
             }
        }
  ?>
```